# "How strong is $\Diamond_\kappa^+$?"

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

In $\text{ZFC}$, we know that $\Diamond_{\kappa}^+ \implies \Diamond_{\kappa}$ and $\Diamond_{\kappa^+} \implies 2^\kappa = \kappa^+$, so that we may think of $\Diamond^+$, i.e. $\Diamond_\kappa^+$ for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, as a strengthening of $\text{GCH}$. I now wonder how strong $\Diamond^+$ is relative to $\text{GCH}$. In fact, assuming $\text{GCH}$, how much of $\Diamond^+$ can we actually get to fail (, how do we accomplish this) and are there any nice statements, which imply $\text{GCH}$ but not $\Diamond^+$?

Comment: I think that you mean that $\Diamond_\kappa\iff 2^\kappa=\kappa^+$ (for $\kappa\geq\omega_1$, of course).

Comment: @Asaf: That subindex on the left hand side should be a $\kappa^+$.

Comment: @Andres: Isn't $\Diamond$ and its "immediate variants" a Jensen-style notation, that $\Diamond_\kappa$ is a sequence of length $\kappa^+$? So $\Diamond_{\omega_1}$ is equivalent to $2^{\aleph_1}=\aleph_2$?

Comment: @Asaf Can you refer me to a proof of $2^\kappa = \kappa^+ \implies \Diamond_{\kappa^+}$?

Comment: No, the subindex indicates here the larger cardinal. So diamond at a large cardinal kappa is a reflection property.

Comment: Ugh. I really hate the notation of these combinatorial principles. It is thoroughly confusing! As if someone just decides to give their talk in Norwegian to an international audience...

Comment: A nice proof of the GCH/diamonds at successors equivalence can be found as Theorem 2.2 in J. Cummings, Notes on singular cardinal combinatorics, Notre Dame Journal of Formal Logic, 46(3), 2005, 251--282.